# Webpack 4 + pug/sass extract/file-loaders not working with multiple imports

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, sass-loader, pug-loader

I'm trying something that *looks* pretty basic with webpack: to include `.pug` and `.scss` files with `import` from Javascript and have the compilation export the respective `.html` and `.css` with the `extract-loader` and `file-loader`.

To make it easy to reproduce/demonstrate, I created a repo here: https://github.com/brianmhunt/broken--pug-loader

The minimal webpack config is pretty trivial, being:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  output: { filename: 'app.js' },
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'index.js'),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'file-loader', options: { name: 'index.html' } },
          'extract-loader',
          'html-loader',
          'pug-html-loader'
        ] },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'file-loader', options: { name: 'main.css' } },
          'extract-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ] }
    ]
  },
}
```

The files are set up/included as:

```
entry: index.js
  import 'one.pug'
    import three.pug
  import 'two.pug'

  import 'abc.scss'
     @import 'ghi.scss'
  import 'def.scss'
```

Only the content from `one.pug` and `three.pug` end up in `index.html`, and only `abc` and `ghi` in the `css`, so it seems then that the second file is ignored by the `extract-loader`.

Among other options, I tried `concat-loader` but my experiments did not yield any useful results.

To replicate the issue:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:brianmhunt/broken--pug-loader.git
$ yarn install
$ yarn run webpack --mode=production
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `include three.pug` in `one.pug` instead of `import` or `require`. for resources use something like img(src="./img/image.png"), webpack will resolve this. I added a file load for png and tested that it then outputs .png files to the dist and sets the `src="d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.png"` correctly.

and then in your `webpack.config` your entry point is just overwriting index.html twice, so you need to do something like

```
  {
    test: /one\.pug$/,
    use: [
      { loader: 'file-loader', options: { name: 'index.html' } },
      'concat-loader',
      'extract-loader',
      'html-loader',
      'pug-html-loader'
    ] },
  {
    test: /two\.pug$/,
      use: [
        { loader: 'file-loader', options: { name: 'index2.html' } },
        'concat-loader',
        'extract-loader',
        'html-loader',
        'pug-html-loader'
      ] },
```

which can be simplified to

`{ loader: 'file-loader', options: { name: '[name].html' } }`, for all files.

and similarly for css files.

https://github.com/cwg999/broken--pug-loader/tree/stackoverflow/cwg999-response

Comment: Thanks Cody; I should have mentioned but there are an arbitrary number of two, three, ..., n pug files; I am sure you agree adding a config section for every file would be absurdly unmaintanable, brittle, and confusing. . With that in mind is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yeah just use `{ loader: 'file-loader', options: { name: '[name].html' } },`

Comment: How does one aggregate these files into one (anticipating hundreds ...)?

Comment: If these aren't seperate entry points for the html then you should just use the `pug` -  `include` feature, shouldn't you (similar to pug 1  including 3)? Also not saying I'm an expert in this either, I never really got pug-loader to work the way I wanted it to.

Comment: Thanks Cody.  The issue is that we've a bunch of different, separate entry points to discrete modules - each with their own JS, CSS and HTML; to make it manageable at scale we'd like to include (and remove) a single entry point (e.g. the `index.js` file) that includes all the dependencies for each module.  You'd think it'd be trivial ... and yet here we are 

Comment: It's a little unclear, so basically you want `require('one.pug')` and `require('two.pug')` to actually merge together? And the reason you dont' want to do this in a `main.pug` file is because it would be in a separate file.  I think there's a "append" loader of sorts...

Comment: Yeah, I tried the `concat` loader, but that didn't seem to do the trick. It's a mystery. 

Comment: You can write a post script loader and concat them all yourself into a new file and remove the files you imported. If you look at that concat loader you'll see it's not a very large plugin... `module.exports = function(content) {
 this.cacheable && this.cacheable();
 this.value = content;
 return content;
}`

Comment: Something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-concat-plugin might work, but I don't think it works for "post webpack emit" type ordeals.

Comment: I’ve gone on to another design so the build system here is no longer needed.  I’m marking this answer as correct because I think it provides the essentials for anyone who also comes across this problem.